# FreeBSD gettytab configuration

Tags: freebsd, tty, serial-console

I have a serial port on my system which is named cuau3 under FreeBSD. I want to change the properties of this port, I can change the device's speed using `/etc/ttys` and `/etc/gettytab` files, but I can't change other properties e.g. parity, stopbits, etc ... . I've added the following entry to the `/etc/gettytab` file :

```
test.std.115200:\
:ep:sp#4800:tc:Pc
```

And also I've changed `/etc/ttys` file

```
cuau3   "/usr/libexec/getty test.std.115200"    cons25  on secure
```

I expect the `/dev/cuau3` device to use even parity and a speed of4800, but when I check the device properties using `stty -f /dev/cuau3`, only the speed changes to 4800 and the parity value doesn't change.

Here's the output of `stty -f /dev/cuau3` after applying the changes using `kill -HUP 1` command.

```
speed 4800 baud;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo
iflags: -icrnl -ixon -ixany -imaxbel -brkint
oflags: -opost tab3
cflags: cs8 -parenb
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stty](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?stty(1)) command directly to change stop and parity bits. For example:

```
stty -f /dev/cuau3 cstopb
```

To make it easier,  put the appropriate commands in a file.
And if you want to do it on bootup, source that file them from `/etc/rc.d` or `/etc/local`/